# Magento 2 - Render cost price in low stock report - Many can use this

Tags: stock, reports, grid-layout, manage-stock

We have a shop, where we want a low stock report with cost prices, so we can see how much we need to pay for these products before buying them.

What I want is to add an extra column with the cost price in the low stock report.

I have tried to add a block in **`reports_report_product_lowstock_grid.xml`**

But I can't see anything new on the grid.

I hope an expert can help, and I'm sure many can use this.

Best regards Martin

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.block.report.product.lowstock.grid.columnSet.price" as="price">
<arguments>
    <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Kost pris</argument>
    <argument name="filter" xsi:type="string">Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Filter\Range</argument>
    <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
    <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">price</argument>
    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">number</argument>
    <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-price</argument>
    <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-price</argument>
</arguments>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can override **reports_report_product_lowstock_grid.xml** in your module

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/ reports_report_product_lowstock_grid.xml
```

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.report.grid.container">
            <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.block.report.product.lowstock.grid">
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.block.report.product.lowstock.grid.columnSet.status" as="status">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</argument>
                            <argument name="sortable" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">status</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-status</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-status</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
             </referenceBlock>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Hope this will help you!

Please let me know if you need my help.